# Can protein obtained from eating insect totally replace red meat, fish and egg white?

Tags: muscle, protein, meat

I am training hard and my goal is to build myself into a guy with **big muscle**.

I know eating properly is something that can't be ignored on my road to success.

I have heard that **insects** can offer **great protein**.

**So can I eat less meat and consume more insects?**

**Can protein obtained from eating insect totally replace red meat, fish and egg white?**

Comment: That's an interesting question, but it would be more suited in the cooking stackexchange. In this one, questions on nutrition are generally off-topic unless they directly relate to physical exercise.

Comment: **"egg white"** - Why *egg white*? It's the second time I'm reading about people here consuming egg white, instead of whole eggs, in quite a short time. The yolk contains more protein and dietary cholesterole is likely **not** the cause of high blood cholesterole levels. So why?

Comment: In theory, yes, you can. Mealwoms, for instance http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S004484861631016X

Comment: @PaulK: People following IIFYM who ran out of fat macros for the day and need just pure protein basically.

Comment: @DeeV I see. It should have been quite obvious.

Comment: I think the big question is if they carry the right amino acids. That's usually what decides whether a source of protein is actually useful, right?

Comment: There are pretty jacked people who don't eat any meat or animal products. Your body doesn't care where the amino acids come from. Meat, insects, fish, lentils, beans, or tofu, it doesn't actually matter much for your muscles

Comment: It helps to compare insects to other well-known sources of protein, like chicken and eggs. So here we go: A typical serving size of crickets is 3.5 ounces. That portion contains 13 grams of protein and 121 calories, In comparison, that same amount of eggs (about two large eggs) contains the exact same amount of protein and only slightly more calories (154). That same amount of chicken contains 31 grams of protein and about 200 calories. https://www.womenshealthmag.com/food/protein-in-insects